# What fires first in GitHub on a "push", the pre-receive hook or the webhook?

Tags: github, githooks

I am working on various hook scripts and was wondering if there could be a possible 'race condition' WRT the firing of similar "push" hooks. For example, if I have a pre-receive hook that uses the default GH environment (e.g., not running in a container), and a webhook that is set to fire on a "push" operation, does one hook fire first, are they fired in-parallel, or is it "random" depending on server load, the hook's functionality, etc? I'm setting up a test scenario, but was wondering if someone had already gone through this and had feedback.

Thanks in advance!